# Создание модели через рефлексию для сохранений Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, рефлексия, сериализация

Я новичок и пишу систему сохранений в Unity, которую хотелось бы использовать и в других своих проектах. В Интернете полно способов сделать сохранения в Unity, но архитектурно-правильных — единицы, если они вообще есть. Надеюсь, таким же как я, этот вопрос и ответ на него будут очень полезены.

Ранее я делал одну модель и писал туда всё, что нужно было сохранять и загружать. Недостатки такого решения очевидны и показывают себя уже через 50 строк в такой модели. Что уж, пока я этот подход и не сменил. *gameData* — экземпляр в базовом классе от *GameData*, в котором множество разных полей.

```cs
protected override void Save()
{
    gameData.currencyAmount = Amount;
}

protected override void Load()
{
    Amount = gameData.currencyAmount;
}
```

Сейчас я в поиске другой системы. Мне ничего не мешало бы создавать отдельную модель для сохранений, но это может явно увеличить количество файлов в проекте и нажатий по клавиатуре. Так что этот вариант оставлю на крайний случай.

Мне бы хотелось как-то динамически создавать модель. Так что пришла идея добавить генерацию модели *model* через рефлексию. Я пока не сильно в этом разбираюсь, так что обратился сюда.

```cs
protected override void Save()
{
    model.Amount = Amount;
}

protected override void Load()
{
    Amount = model.Amount;
}
```

Извиняюсь, если что-то сформулировал или употребил неправильно. Если у вас есть другое, но не менее эффективное и простое, решение для сохранений в Unity, можете ответить им сразу. Буду рад всем мыслям и идеям в комментариях. Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте словарь, ложите туда свои значения(не забудьте только проверить, что ключ еще не был создан). А вообще много файлов с моделями - это совсем не проблема, главное чтобы все было правильно продумано. А вот создание "динамической" модели что то из ряда так себе

Comment: В вашем случае нужно создавать IL код (собственно метод). Вам понадобятся команды ldfld stfld. Специально под вас может кто-то и напишет код генерации, сомневаюсь, но может у кого-то есть наработки - возможно поделяться (нотка сомнения). Попробуйте поищите на гите по ключам Reflection c# stfld может что подходящее найдете. Если вы понимаете что такое IL код, и как должен ваш выглядеть - то самостоятельно создать получится. Для старта... вам сюда http://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-define-and-execute-dynamic-methods

Comment: Сериализация и рефлексия - это немножно разные вещи. Сериализация впринципе в отдельных случаях возможна без рефлексии. А рефлексия не означает сериализацию, это просто библиотека, которая позволяет сделать обращения к любым методам свойствам полям существующих обьектов. В упрощенном виде, вы можете для ваших классов взять метод GetFields http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfields?view=netframework-4.8 и по перечислению полей - поприсваивать в цикле значения. это будет проще чем создание через IL, но медленнее.

Comment: Вам нужен `singleton` класс в котором `dictionary` с системой сохранения и загрузки в обычный `txt`, предварительно шифруя этот текст.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Какой ключ можно использовать в Dictionary? Полагаю, можно было бы находить имя класса и переменной как ключ и записывать значение, но что если я их поменяю. Не знаете какие есть более надежные способы?